# QML: how to register user custom shortcut

Tags: qml, pyside2

I'm currently learning Qt by developing a simple desktop app with Python and QML. The document about `Pyside2` with `QML` is surprisingly insufficient.

Anyway, now I'm struggling with user custom shortcut key registering.

Some app have a text field in which you can press a key combination and that combination will show in the text field. something like this image

[image]

According to the official document, there's a [`QKeySequenceEdit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequenceedit.html)  in C++.

Is there any way to do this in `QML`? Or at least in `Pyside2`?

Or maybe QML is not a good choice for GUI from beginning?

---

**update**

strange characters using @folibis's answer

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> left to right.

---

**update 2**
I ended up with code below based on @folibis's answer:

```
var keyModifiers = [
    {"name": "Ctrl", "code": Qt.ControlModifier},
    {"name": "Shift", "code": Qt.ShiftModifier},
    {"name": "Alt", "code": Qt.AltModifier},
    {"name": "Meta", "code": Qt.MetaModifier},
    // {"name": "Keypad", "code": Qt.KeypadModifier},
    {"name": "GroupSwitch", "code": Qt.GroupSwitchModifier}    
]
var numpadKeycodes = [
    {"name": "Del", "code": Qt.Key_Period},
    {"name": "+", "code": Qt.Key_Plus},
    {"name": "*", "code": Qt.Key_Asterisk},
    {"name": "-", "code": Qt.Key_Minus},
    {"name": "/", "code": Qt.Key_Slash},
    {"name": "0", "code": Qt.Key_0},
    {"name": "1", "code": Qt.Key_1},
    ...   
]
var keycodes = [
    ...
    {"name": "/", "code": Qt.Key_Question}, // ?
    {"name": "2", "code": Qt.Key_At}, // @
    {"name": "A", "code": Qt.Key_A},
    {"name": "B", "code": Qt.Key_B},
    {"name": "C", "code": Qt.Key_C},
    ....
]

TextField {
    id: txt
    readOnly: true

    Keys.onPressed: {
        var str = "";
        var text;
        keyModifiers.forEach(modifier => {
            if(event.modifiers & modifier.code) {
                str += `${modifier.name} + `;
            }
        });
        // Numpad keys
        if (event.modifiers & Qt.KeypadModifier) {
            str += "Num "
            text = numpadKeycodes.some(keycode => {
                if (keycode.code === event.key) {
                    str += keycode.name;
                    return keycode.name
                }
            });
        } else {
            text = keycodes.some(keycode => {
                if (keycode.code === event.key) {
                    str += keycode.name;
                    return keycode.name
                }
            });
        }
        if (str === "" && !text) {
            str = "None"
        }
        txt.text = str;
    }
    Keys.onReleased: {
        if (txt.text.endsWith(" ")) {
            txt.text = "None"
        }
    }
}
```

Job's done but too much code... If there's a better way, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beauty of QML is that you can easy do whatever you want. As for your issue you can implement something like the following:

```js
TextField {
    id: txt
    readOnly: true
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    Keys.onPressed: {
        var str = '';
        var arr = {
            'Shift': Qt.ShiftModifier,
            'Ctrl': Qt.ControlModifier,
            'Alt': Qt.AltModifier,
            'Meta': Qt.MetaModifier,
            'Keypad': Qt.KeypadModifier,
            'GroupSwitch': Qt.GroupSwitchModifier };

        for(var key in arr) {
            var value = arr[key];
            if(event.modifiers & value) {
                str += (str === '' ? '' : '-') + key;
            }
        }
        if(event.text !== '')
            str += (str === '' ? '' : '-') + event.text;
        txt.text = str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you so much!! By the way, is there any function like `preventDefault()`? `shift` + any letter for example "a", shows "shift-A"; and on my Windows 10, `CTRL` + any letter shows some strange characters. I updated my question with an image of characters.

Comment: Maybe you want to use [KeyEvent.key](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keyevent.html#key-prop) instead? `nativeScanCode` also may be relevant in this case. Make a small research what event returns.