# How to use QKeySequence or QKeySequenceEdit from QML?

Tags: qt, qml

Is it possible to use a QKeySequence or QKeySequenceEdit in QML? I only see the documentation for C++ https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#details

To provide context, I want a QKeySequence to be input by the user of the application so that I can pass it to my C++ backend so that I can hook into native OS APIs and also serialize it to file.

I do not want to actually establish the shortcut within Qt.

Comment: See [Shortcut.sequence](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shortcut.html#sequence-prop).

Comment: mmm, I think I'm starting to understand you. You want something similar to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequenceedit.html but in QML

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes that looks like exactly what I want! Or if it doesn't exist, an easy way to re-implement it?

Comment: I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61983774/qml-how-to-register-user-custom-shortcut, which looks unsatisfactory. The OP spent a lot of code translating key codes to ascii symbols, which is already accomplished by QKeySequence

Comment: @Mark I recommend you to point out that you want to implement an Item with a behavior like to QKeysequenceEdit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new object that wraps the `QKeySequence::toString` and makes it available from QML so I wouldn't have to re-implement a massive switch-case in QML.

```
#ifndef QMLUTIL_H
#define QMLUTIL_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QKeySequence>

// A singleton object to implement C++ functions that can be called from QML
class QmlUtil : public QObject{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE bool isKeyUnknown(const int key) {
        // weird key codes that appear when modifiers
        // are pressed without accompanying standard keys
        constexpr int NO_KEY_LOW = 16777248;
        constexpr int NO_KEY_HIGH = 16777251;
        if (NO_KEY_LOW <= key && key <= NO_KEY_HIGH) {
           return true;
        }

        if (key == Qt::Key_unknown) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE QString keyToString(const int key, const int modifiers){
        if (!isKeyUnknown(key)) {
            return QKeySequence(key | modifiers).toString();
        } else {
            // Change to "Ctrl+[garbage]" to "Ctrl+_"
            QString modifierOnlyString = QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Underscore | modifiers).toString();

            // Change "Ctrl+_" to "Ctrl+..."
            modifierOnlyString.replace("_", "...");
            return modifierOnlyString;
        }
    }
};
```

To expose this in QML, you have to say `engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("qmlUtil",  new QmlUtil());` in your `main.cpp` where you are setting up your QQmlEngine.

Then you can type `qmlUtil.keyToString(event.key, event.modifiers)` in QML to turn a keyboard event to a string.

You can combine that with the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64839234/353407 replacing the individual cases with a single function call to `qmlUtil.keyToString`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a string to the `sequence` property from `Shortcut`, see [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shortcut.html#sequence-prop).

For example if you want to chain <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, you specify the following:

```
Shortcut {
    sequence: "cltr+m,ctrl+t"
    onActivated: console.log("you activated turbo mode")
}
```

It's even possible to assign multiple keyboard shortcuts to the same action, using the `sequences` (plural) property: [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shortcut.html#sequences-prop)

Comment: What if I don't want to bind the sequence to an actual shortcut? What I want is for the user to specify a keysequence which I can pass to my backend because I need to do implement some OS specific behavior (the shortcut should be triggered even if the application is not focused)

Comment: I also want to save and load this shortcut from a plaintext config file

Comment: @eyllanesc The backend is already configured to call the correct system libraries. What remains is to be able to alter the shortcut from QML, and then have back end and front end synchronized with respect to what the shortcut is.

Comment: @eyllanesc Exactly. So the idea is to capture a keysequence from the user and then call the backend function SetOSHotkey(userkeysequence). Does that clarify the question?